# How to reference an MBean attribute within Spring XML configuration

Tags: xml, spring, jmx

we are running an ActiveMQ broker - which is configured via Spring XML - within a JBoss 7.

We want to re-use the socket-binding-groups of JBoss to make the ActiveMQ broker port dynamically configurable.

JBoss exposes the ports for the socket-binding-groups via JMX. So our current idea is to access the MBean (and it's port attribute) from within the Spring XML and inject it somehow at the right place.

This is our current broker-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"/>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        useJmx="true" useShutdownHook="false" persistent="true" brokerName="localhost">

...         
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:${amq.port}?trace=true?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireformat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

As you can see we are currently referencing a system property `amq.port` from within the configuration using Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Is there a way to let the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` create a property by retrieving an MBean attribute (or sth. similar)?

Kind regards,
Michael

Comment: How about a MethodInvoker against the MBeanServer ?

Comment: I read about this and already thought it might help - but I'm an absolute Spring beginner! I also did not find a real good example. Could you give me a code example?